# How can I get Instagram user/account id from a username/profile?

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram, instagram-api

I'm working on a feature that takes an Instagram username and gleans the account id (similar to this [feature on codeofaninja](https://codeofaninja.com/tools/find-instagram-user-id/)). In the prior iteration, I had code on the backend that fetches the instagram page of the username and scrapes the account id from the info in the HTML. This still works fine on my local machine, however recently on a deployed server, I seem to be getting a different document that seems like a sign-in wall. Perhaps an anti scraping tactic from Instagram? (Interesting enough I noticed that many websites that have the same feature stopped working as well, including the codeofaninja site).

I have looked at some of the Instagram developer APIs and there are things that allow a app to get user profile info, but requires authentication into that user. These APIs seem like they're mostly built to connect the user's account to the app rather than allowing a third party to get the basic account information. Am I missing something in their API feature? Is Instagram actively forbidding sites from accessing basic profile info that would otherwise be available on the source page in a regular browser? Does anyone know a way for a third party server to be able to check the Instagram account id from a username?

Comment: Did you find a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.instagram.com/developer/

The update states that the basic permissions were disabled a few weeks ago; this is probably why your page and codeofaninja dosen't work anymore. You can use the Instagram Basic Display API instead

Comment: We were not using their api, rather scraping the account id from a profile page requested within a flask app. Correct me if I'm wrong, but this update does not mention changes to what my app on a server would see in that request

Comment: also, like i mentioned the basic display API does not fit my use case since it basically connects a user's profile to an app after authentication

Comment: oh, what is the use for this then if it’s not for authentication of sorts

Comment: i just need to return an account id, given any public username